# copy one table to second table with current date

Tags: php, mysql

hy i am using Mysql (phpmyadmin) with php and i have two tables table1(id,name) and table2(id,date,name)

---

now i want to copy all rows of table1 to table2 and in table2 in date column should store current date of system, for this am trying following query which is giving error

---

```
'INSERT INTO table2 (id, Date, name)SELECT id,'.date("Y-m-d",mktime()).'nae FROM table1 WHERE id=2'
```

---

can you correct my query ? i tried different ways but not working any method. there is no error in connection with database all are ok, i tested connection its fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

`'INSERT INTO table2 (id, Date, name) SELECT id,"'.date("Y-m-d",mktime()).'",name FROM table1 WHERE id=2'`

Comment: what is difference between my and your query ? btw its not working

Comment: "" around date, added "," before name, you misspelled name.

Comment: Can you share the exact query you tried, and the error message you get?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'mktime()),name FROM table1 WHERE id=2' at line 1

Comment: mktime() is supposed to be PHP code, not part of the MySQL query, right? Try printing the SQL string first, something is still wrong with your use of quotes.